# Как через переменную добавить id в pug?

Tags: jade, pug

Привет!
У меня есть миксин, и мне в некоторых местах, в ссылке необходимо добавить в id, как через переменную и условие можно сделать?

```
mixin product-slider-item(title, image, text, new1, finger)
+e.item(class!=attributes.class)
    +e('a').link(href='javascript:void(0);' title='#{title}' class!=attributes.class)
        if new1 == true
            +all-icons('--catalog-novinka --catalog', '--catalog', true)
        if finger == true
            +all-icons('--sticker --catalog-sticker', '--catalog', true)
        +e.image-wrap(class!=attributes.class)
            +e('img').image(src="#{image}" alt="" class!=attributes.class)
        +e.info(class!=attributes.class)
            +e.title #{title}
            +e.text
                span #{text}
            +e.more-link(class!=attributes.class)
                span ПОДРОБНЕЕ
```

На выходе необходимо получить
в первом случае

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="U5011" **data-id="1"** class="b-product-slider__link b-product-slider__link--catalog"></a>
```

во втором случае

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="U5011" class="b-product-slider__link b-product-slider__link--catalog"></a>
```

Comment: добавь пример вызова с параметрами и ожидаемого результата

Comment: как ты вызываешь mixin для первого и второго случаев? с какими параметрами?

Comment: @Grundy в этом то и вопрос, все зависит от того как записать.  Либо как &attributes(что у меня не вышло), либо через true/false как-то.

Comment: непонятно. Что ты на вход хочешь подавать? добавлять data-id или нет? или название для `data-*` или значение для `data-id`?

Comment: @Grundy на вход подается значение для data-id, и если значения нет, то data-id не выводится совсем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [`&attributes`](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attributes) и объект [`attributes`](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-attributes) следующим образом

```
//- Declaration
mixin mmm()
  a()&attributes(attributes)

//- Use
+mmm()(data-id="10")
```

Результатом будет

```
<a data-id="10"></a>
```