# Вызов миксина с нужным набором параметров

Tags: javascript, html, jade

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть mixin в Jade для формы. Один mixin но из него можно вызвать 3 разных окна, перебрав нужные параметры. Как вызвать один я разобрался, но как мне вызвать например только третий, если раскоментировать остальные - вызовутся все сразу. Нужно добавить в список параметров id или class каждой форме? Подскажите пожалуйста кто хорошо разбирается...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
//- Форма Задать вопрос (Задать вопрос, ФИО, телефон, E-Mail, Ваш вопрос, Чекбокс)
+form-popup("Задать вопрос", true, true, true, true, false)

//- Форма Заказать звонок (Заказать звонок, ФИО, телефон, E-Mail, Чекбокс)
//- +form-popup("Заказать звонок",true, true, false, true, false)

//- Форма Ваша заявка отправлена (Ваша заявка отправлена, Спасибо за обращение)
//- +form-popup("Ваша заявка отправлена",false, false, false, false, true)
```

Comment: добавь код как код а не как картинку

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил..

Comment: Так себе, по-моему, выглядит решение в виде передачи вагона bool-ов в метод.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь там есть условия: `if` например. Кстати, Jade - это pug сейчас?

Comment: Grundy - да, это сейчас pug

Comment: То есть через атрибут data-id я не смогу вызвать нужный мне набор?

Comment: не понял последний комментарий

Comment: а вот это не тот же самый вопрос? [Как через переменную добавить id в pug?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/661498/186999)

Comment: Ну мне нужно так : есть форма на сайте, точнее 3 разных но все они вызываются из одного миксина, что бы на каждую форму не делать отдельный. Мне нужно что бы при нажатии кнопку "Заполнить форму" открывалась первая форма, а после нажатия "Отправить" открывалась 3яя.

Comment: проще сделать отдельные mixin на каждую форму чем вертеть кучи условий и параметров

Comment: я тоже думаю что легче, но к сожалению поставили задачу так..